# Kurento - WebRTC does not work on linux virtual machine azure server

Tags: linux, azure, webrtc, kurento

I implement Kurento on my local, it works ok.
When I deploy it on linux vm azure server, kurento does not work.
I know that Kurento just works with UDP default, if want it works on TCP, I have to config turn server for kurento. After config turn server of google for kurento, but it still does not work.
And then i try to change Azure to UDP, but I just found down the guider for window vm, it is config on endpoint. 
Who knows how to resolve this problem, make kurento work on azure server, please give me your ideas.

Comment: define doesn't work. Linux on Azure is just a regular linux distro, why won't it work?

Comment: Define doesn't work: It means Kurento media server after deploy on azure not working. Client do not receive media stream from kurento anymore. But no error display when i debug.
Someone has the same, but it's too long time ago, i can not resolve follow it any more.
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/kurento/GJipAHvjIEg

Comment: can you connect to the vm?

Comment: Of course, yes.

Comment: Your VM is ARM mode or classic VM?

Comment: For an ARM VM, you should open port on Azure NSG, `netstat -putan | grep kurento` what the result?

Comment: Thank you, this is result after i run sudo netstat -putan | grep kurento
tcp6       0      0 :::8888                 :::*                    LISTEN      8103/kurento-media-
tcp6       0      0 127.0.0.1:8888          127.0.0.1:37478         ESTABLISHED 8103/kurento-media-
tcp6       0      0 127.0.0.1:8888          127.0.0.1:37462         ESTABLISHED 8103/kurento-media-
tcp6       0      0 127.0.0.1:8888          127.0.0.1:37466
....

Comment: I test the same result with you. The port listening on `tcp6` not `tcp`. You should modify it. Azure does not support `ipv6` directly.

Comment: Do you check port 8443 is listening on `0.0.0.0`?

Comment: yes, even i can access on 8443 to see template of site.. Just when i try to make video call on this site, it not work.

Comment: I test the same result with you. The port listening on tcp6 not tcp. You should modify it. Azure does not support ipv6 directly. 
How i modify it? please

Comment: You had better modify the service is listening on tcp, but I don't find anything about it.

Comment: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/kurento/6I6_b4dH0Mo

Answer (score 0):

First off, Azure does not allow UDP traffic.

On TCP, since you get no error, it sems like the problem is with the network. Assuming that you are trying to tx/rx data from Azure to a server/client outside of Azure, make sure you create/map the proper ports from the Azure public IP endpoint to your VM. You can do this from the Azure portal. Even if the port is open on the VM, you still need to map ports from the public IP to the VM; sort of like port forwarding in a home router.

I hope this helps!

Comment: Yes, thanks for your answer.
Firstly, i'm sure my azure server is working: https://gethearti.com
.Secondly, after i install room kurento from: 
http://doc-kurento-room.readthedocs.io/en/stable/quick_start.html
it works on local. But on azure it does not(of course i install and build successfull on azure, just when i try to gethearti.com:8443. It just show me the template, video call not work). i also did open port 8443 
 TCP (port when i run kurento room) on azure server.
Anything else wrong? please